# Convert encoding of TMemoryStream to utf8

Tags: delphi

I have a file opened in `TMemoryStream`. Its current encoding can be ANSI or UTF8 with BOM. I have to convert the encoding of `TMemoryStream` to `UTF8`. How do I do that?

Comment: Let's start with the obvious. If you care about efficiency, why read it into memory before converting it? A classic mistake is to think that `TMemoryStream` is the only implementation of `TStream` that matters. If efficiency matters surely you want to read using a `TFileStream`, convert, and then write to the `TMemoryStream`. Cut out the middle man. Having said all of that, if you are reading from disk then I suggest that the disk access dominates so as to render the rest of the process irrelevant. Finally, giving advice on performance requires detailed knowledge of usage. We don't have that.

Comment: Take a look at TEncoding.UTF8.

Comment: Thanks David and Rudy for quick response. My file is already opened in memorystream. I cannot change it. I have to convert it's encoding. After converting to utf8, I have to make some changes in it and again save it to disk in it's original encoding. This is being done to stop extended characters from corrupting the file.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you actually care about efficiency, because you seem to be taking decisions that inevitably lead to inefficient solutions. One wonders why the file was created with an ANSI encoding in the first place. You still have not provided any real context and usage. I think it is impossible to answer the question "what is the most efficient way to do it?"

Comment: Ok David. Let me try to give context here. We receive file from client. So, it can be encoded in ANSI. We cannot control it. But we don't have a foolproof mechanism to identify the file's encoding. Project requirement does not allow any scope for mistake and performance can take a hit here. So, File is opened in memorystream and traversed till the end to identify it's encoding. If a file has extended character, we have to convert the memorystream to utf8 to avoid mishaps from extended characters. After we make required changes, we have to again save it in original encoding.

Comment: so, for us, efficiency comes into context when the we are trying to convert TMemorystream to utf8.

Comment: You cannot reliably distinguish between an ANSI file and a UTF-8. In other words, it is possible for the same file to be valid when interpreted as either ANSI or UTF-8. You have no way of telling which it is. You can make a good educated guess based on hueristics. But that's the best you can manage. So what you describe is in fact impossible.

Comment: Yes agree with that. But we are concerned with extended characters. If ANSI file has any extended character, then we have to change it's encoding. This serves our purpose. With this assumption, can you help me in getting the best approach.

Comment: What if the file is encoded in UTF-8 already? How can you tell it apart from an ANSI file? As others have mentioned, `TEncoding` offers the functionality that you need. Feel free to read about it in the documentation. You should be able to work out the code now that you know about `TEncoding`. However, if I understand you correctly, what you are attempting is impossible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The question mentions "ANSI or UTF-8 with BOM". Shouldn't it be sufficient to check for the BOM?

Comment: Your question implies that any UTF-8 input will have a BOM. So I suppose you could hope that you never see an ANSI file that is starts with a UTF-8 BOM. If that is so then you can simply check the first three characters of the file, and then convert. In which case you don't need to load it into a memory stream at all. Anyway, I removed the section in the question concerning efficiency since I'm pretty sure that's not relevant.

Comment: @user3857505 have a look at `TStreamReader` and `TStreamWriter`. First detect the input stream's encoding and create a reader using that encoding, then create a writer using UTF-8, then read Unicode strings from the reader in a loop and write them to the writer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to change the `TMemoryStream` to its descendant `TBytesStream` you can just use the `Convert` function from `TEncoding`.

```
var
  stream: TBytesStream;
  bytes: TBytesStream;
  ...
  TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding(stream.Bytes, curEncoding);
  if curEncoding <> TEncoding.UTF8 then begin
    bytes := TEncoding.Convert(curEncoding, TEncoding.UTF8, stream.Bytes);
    stream.Free;
    stream := TBytesStream.Create(bytes);
  end;
```

Not sure if it is the most efficient way, but at least it is one way and it only needs a couple of lines, which in turn is also some sort of efficiency.

Comment: It won't be very efficient for large files, so hope you work with small files. Also, if `GetBufferEncoding()` doesn't detect a BOM then it returns `TEncoding.Default`, which represents the OS default ANSI charset which might not be the same ANSI encoding of the file. `TEncoding` can't actually detect the real ANSI charset because it doesn't perform any heuristics to do so. You will have to do that manually if it matters.

Comment: Hello Uwe. This line doesn't work:stream.Bytes := TEncoding.Convert(curEncoding, TEncoding.UTF8, stream.Bytes); stream.Bytes is read-only.